# C: unknown input from user

Tags: c, input, scanf

I wish to get input from a user in C. There are two options:
`char` and then `int` *(`scanf("%c, %d", &mychar, &myint)`)*
or a `string`.

My question is how to check the user input line if I don't know what the user is going to input - a string or the char/int combination. Thanks!

Comment: is there really a comma `,` as the second input character?

Answer (score 6):

Input a string with `fgets`, then try `sscanf` on it, and check the result for success/failure. If you get `2`, you've successfully read a character and an integer. If you get anything else, `sscanf` failed to read the format you specified, so use the original string.

You can even read the format `"%c, %d%c"` (don't forget to give it a char variable to read the third parameter into) in order to see if a char and an integer were all there was, for strict error checking: `"x, 18trashtrash"` will make `sscanf` return `3`, while a nice `"x, 18"` will give you `2`.

Comment: but in case of "c, c" won't i get 2 as well? in my case i don't have a , so if I read
"%c %d%c" ill get 2 for any string input, wont i?

Comment: No, because `sscanf` will refuse to read the second `c` with `%d`; so you get `1` (for correctly read `%c`)